# mysql thread and tomcat thread should be the same for a better perfoming?

Tags: linux, mysql, configuration, tomcat, optimization

my tomcat instance on ubuntu server running with mysql and only the application has access to mysql (only the service-user tomcat). I have small experience level with optimizing with mysql and tomcat. 
For a good perfomance should the maxthread value tomcat the same like mysql ?

For any help, im grateful

kind regards

blackbeard

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to `max_connections` in MySQL?  What are the values now?  If you have more than, say, 20, active threads running, you need to worry about optimizing the queries.

It is not critical that the settings be the same, or even similar.  Performance issues stem from slow queries, bursts of queries, etc.  Do you have any symptoms of "bad performance"?

Comment: the max connections default value of my mysql community edition is 151. If im running htop i see 30 pid for my mysql istance.

Comment: @beardblack Please post your HTOP report so we can see your HTOP output page 1.